# How? Bash loop, sed and inserting the current loop's filename into the sed pattern space

Tags: bash, sed, filenames

The goal:
To loop through a folder of text files, extract all the end-of-line, word-wrapped, hyphenated words, and collate them into a list.

```
001.txt be-littled
001.txt dev-eloper
002.txt sand-wich
...
```

The purpose is to scan the list and differentiate the valid hyphenated words from the merely word-wrapped (i.e., twenty-four versus dev-eloper).

My current Bash/sed script catches most (enough) of the words correctly. I know it needs some tweaking (like when the hyphenated word ends the paragraph).

But right now, I can't get the current filename into the pattern space.

```
for f in *.txt
  do
    sed -rn 'N;/PATTERN/!{D};s:PATTERN:\3-\5\n\7:;P;D' * > output.txt;
  done
```

..where PATTERN = (^.*)( +)(.+)(-\n)(\S+)( +)(.*$)

or

```
for f in *.txt; do sed -rn 'N;/(^.*)( +)(.+)(-\n)(\S+)( +)(.*$)/!{D};s:(^.*)( +)(.+)(-\n)(\S+)( +)(.*$):\3-\5\n\7:;P;D' * > output.txt;done
```

I tried putting '"$f"' just before the \3 but that just prepends the last page on all lines (i.e., '250.txt be-littled').

I suspect my code isn't doing exactly what I think its doing. :-) Maybe I don't grok the loop order of sed within bash.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 and just started learning bash and sed a few weeks ago. I'm open to suggestions.

Thanks,

Comment: Could you perhaps construct a simpler regex example, in order to make the code in your question easier to read?

Comment: either you should use `for f in *.txt ; do sed ' ....' $f >> output ; done` OR `sed '....' * >> output`. Your current construct processing all files each time through the loop. Fix that and then see what your problem looks like. Good luck.

Comment: Would you mind to give an example of your the cases `end-of-line, word-wrapped, hyphenated words`? End of line and hyphenated is actually ok, but what do you mean with `word-wrapped`? **andalso**, shall a matching have **all** of these characteristics, or one of the is enough to qualify a matching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand exactly why you didn't succeed with writing the file name. You wrote that you tried with `'"$f"'` before `\3`, I think that should work. However I did almost the same but use double quote for the whole sed-command instead so I don't have to use `'"..."'` construct.
You should also use `>>` instead of `>` when writing to the result file, otherwise you overwrite the result file for every new file in the loop.
It can be a typo, but you have `... * > output.txt` at the end of the sed line, should be `$f` instead of `*` I think.

Using double quote for the sed command, space after `!` in `! {D}`, `>> output.txt` and `$f` in the substitution to write the file name (also using `@` as substitute delimiter to be able to use `<file>:` in the result):

```
for f in *.txt; do
  sed -rn "N;/(^.*)( +)(.+)(-\n)(\S+)( +)(.*$)/! {D};s@(^.*)( +)(.+)(-\n)(\S+)( +)(.*$)@$f: \3-\5\n\7@;P;D" $f >> output.txt
done
```

I haven't reviewed your pattern, but it seems so work when I tested it.

I tried it on two small files, one with the wrapped words in your question, and another one with some lines with "dummy words".

```
[]$ cat tf1.txt
asdf asdf be-
littled asdf asdf
asfd dev-
eloper asdf sand-
wich asdf asdf.
[]$ cat tf2.txt
asfd abc-
de lsdk laskfjd
asdf asdf 1234-
56 sdl sdg
sdfg
```

Output:

```
[]$ ./tfwordwrap.sh
tf1.txt: be-littled
tf1.txt: dev-eloper
tf1.txt: sand-wich
tf2.txt: abc-de
tf2.txt: 1234-56
```

Comment: That did it. I didn't know about ">>". I'd probably already solved my problem several times but for the 2nd ">". :-)

Yes, the * at the end had been $f multiple times. 

However, when I enclosed everything in double-quotes I got a "bash: !{D}: event not found" error. But single quotes worked just fine. And the "@" helped my output look nicer. 

Thanks, 2 weeks of intermittent head smashing comes to an end.

Comment: I was testing this using a script, there it seems that `!{D}` is ok. When from command line there must be a space between `!` and `{D}`. `!{...}` probably means something to bash, don't know what. I edited my answer accordingly. So if you change to `! {D}` you can use double quotes for the whole sed command.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea whatsoever of what you mean by `word-wrapped`, but this may work:

```
grep -oH "[^ ]*-[^ ]*$" *.txt | sed 's/:/ /'
```

The trailing `sed` call is just to make the output equal yours -- it replaces the first `:` added by `grep` by a white space.

Output:

```
$ cat 001.txt 
be-littled
dev-eloper

$ cat 002.txt 
sand-wich

$ grep -oH "[^ ]*-[^ ]*$" *.txt | sed 's/:/ /'
001.txt be-littled
001.txt dev-eloper
002.txt sand-wich
```

**Note**: to improve the expression used  in `grep` to fit whatever may be your needs, it's first necessary to learn your requirements -- and I really didn't get the idea from `word-wrapped`;

Comment: By word-wrapped I mean a word the starts on one line and continues on the next -- I think that's what it's called. :-) Your grep command catches the first part of the word but not the second part.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, how to get at the current file name with sed. If you don't mind using perl, try this perl script instead

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $hyphen;

while (<>) {
    next if (m/^\s*$/);

    if ($hyphen) {
        m/^\s*(\w+)/;
        print "$1\n";
        $hyphen = 0;
    }

    if (m/(\w+-)\s*$/) {
        print "$ARGV $1";
        $hyphen = 1;
    }
}
```

This script prints the last hyphenated part of a line together with the file name and sets a flag. In the next line it looks for this flag and prints the first word of the line. It also skips empty lines.

You call it as

```
perl hyphen.pl file1.txt file2.txt ...
```

Comment: Your code seems to work. Somewhat. I haven't checked all 254 text files that I have but I do know that the first hyphenated word appears on 007.txt but your code catches its first word on 008.txt. Your code ends on the correct file with the correct words.

Also, between my pages 036.txt and 037.txt I get an error:

Use of uninitialized value $1 in concatenation (.) or string at hyphen.pl line 11, <> line 1242.

I called your code "hyphen.pl" and ran it with the command "perl hyphen.pl *.txt" . I've never programmed in Perl.

Thanks, my next topics to learn are Perl and awk. :-)

Comment: @Dances_with_Wools I updated the script to allow for white space at the end or beginning of a line. Maybe that's the problem here. When the script finds a hyphen at the end of a line, it expects the remainder of the word to be on the following line.

Comment: OK. I got the same results as before. So I looked more closely at files 007.txt (which your code missed) and 037.txt (that still give the error code). 

It turns out that on my page 037.txt a line ends with "sun-" and the next line starts with ".light". Damn OCR! :-)

And 007.txt has two line-ending hyphenated words: "harm-less."  and "Be-tween"

I don't know enough Perl to understand how your code misses them. But it looks like 244an has solved my problem with some extra sed details. Thanks.